Does utf8mb4:0900-ai_ci distinguish between Chinese and English parentheses
I want to replace utf8mb4_general_ci with utf8mb4:0900-ai_ci in MySQL, but it triggers a unique index. I found that the only difference between the two data entries is the parentheses.
I would like to know if utf8mb4:0900-ai_ci does not distinguish between Chinese and English parentheses

From this answer, I think utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci be able to distinguish between China and English parentheses because it is based on the official Unicode rules
